# Recognizing hashtag symbol

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to use Google Cloud Vision with TEXT_DETECTION to try and do OCR on pictures with hashtags.  But I can't get the hashtag symbol recognized.  Any ideas?

Comment: can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: Could you provide a link to an image that you are having the problem with?